# How to set specific width for bootstrap table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, width

My html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td>User Count</td>
                    <td>@Model.UserCount</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `width="600"` is ignored. I read somewhere that this is because the table fills up the container 100%. But how to override this and set a specific width for the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `style="width:600px"` rather than the `width=600`.
Or you can do that in the style sheet:

```
.table {width:600px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below, it is working for me:

```css
.table
{
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td>User Count</td>
                    <td>@Model.UserCount</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```